# Dump JSON to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Continuing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628673/how-to-get-nested-json-file), i confuse where should I put and how to dump it?
This below is the answer from previous question

```
found_user = True
for user in json_load['user_id']:
    if user['USER ID'] == id_card:
        user_warn_level = user["WARNING"]
        user_warn_level_inc = user_warn_level + 1
        json_load["WARNING"] = user_warn_level_inc
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(json_load, f)
        f.truncate()
        found_user = True
        break
    if not found_user:
        write_json(dump_data)
```

Anyone knows, where is my fault?

Comment: _where is my fault_ You haven't explained what the problem is...

Comment: I agree with @JohnGordon - missing some relevant code, or has irrelevant code in the question. Please clarify the question. I think the question is how to load/dump from/to json<-->python-dict, I placed an answer below

Comment: Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. You should make sure to ask a clear question that can stand on its own; only refer to the other question for reference. It should be clear what *problem you are trying to solve*, what the "it" is that you are trying to dump; what you expect to happen as a result, what happens instead when you run your code, and how that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, check out json documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) 
This is what I do for loading/unloading from json<->python-dict:

```py
>>> import json
>>> s = json.dumps({'a':'b'})
>>> s
'{"a": "b"}'
>>> json.loads(s)
{'a': 'b'}
```

Also - missing some information - what is the file you are reading from/manipulating?